# So, ya feelin' lucky about dis Riley?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, steganography

> My prefix is a big ol' ass,
>   My infix always comes before;
>   My suffix straight up lies bruv',
>   About the answer that I bore,
>   I told ya who I am already, know what I mean?

**Note:**

*The Accepted answer should both answer the Riley and find all the hidden clues.*

***Hint***

> Clues are hidden in both the title and the rhyme, once you find the answer everything will make sense, Good Luck.

***Hint 2:***

> Found after *rainfall*, in all *continent*,
> Can be found also in *sinful intent*.

Comment: Hmm... (ROT13) vf "tbbq yhpx" nyfb n uvag? Orvat yhpxl vf ersreerq gb va gur gvgyr...

Comment: it is actually ;)

Comment: Just a hint - don't try to google search "big ol' ass" :D

Comment: ha ha, what did ya stumble onto? :P

Comment: Am I allowed to ask how many letters the word has, or will that give the answer away?

Comment: i pretty much already gave away the answer in the riddle itself, hence the steganography tag :P all you need is to find it and then explain the riddle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My prefix is a big ol' ass,

> Big "S"

My infix always comes before;

> Eve

My suffix straight up lies bruv',

> Even because the 7 is odd this can't be true.

About the answer that I bore,
I told ya who I am already, know what I mean?

> Seven

Clues are hidden in both the title and the rhyme, once you find the answer everything will make sense, Good Luck.

> The rhyme acrostic spells "SEVEN" and the title refers to it being a lucky number.

Found after rainfall, in all continent,
Can be found also in sinful intent.

> A rainbow and seven deadly sins.

Also

> From  OP there are seven words in the title.

Comment: rot13(frira vf n yhpxl ahzore, nyfb gurer ner frira qrnqyl fvaf!). I think you are on to something here!

Comment: QuantumTwinkie: r13(znlor zber uryc sbe gur Evyrl: N ovt by' NFF = n ovt by' F. Nyjnlf pbzrf orsber = RIR. (Cbffvoyr: vs lbh'er gelvat gb fnl Lrf, naq lbh'er ylvat lbh'q fnl Ab, be A)....haha

Comment: Ooo thanks @El-Guest I will use that :D

Comment: Anytime @QuantumTwinkie, go claim that bounty, friend!!

Comment: gabbo seems to have found the rainfall clue as well!

Comment: The Answer is correct and you found most of the clues, the suffix is still wrong though.. gonna accept it tomorrow, hopefully you'll get the suffix as well.. for the bounty i might wait until the last day for more people to see the riddle, if that's okay..

Comment: Hurray!! I will look again at the suffix :D @ShahriarMahmudSajid

Comment: Is the suffix better @ShahriarMahmudSajid? :)

Comment: yes, its correct now..

Comment: also there are exactly seven words in the title

Comment: Added it @ShahriarMahmudSajid :D

Comment: **Congrats** on your bounty reward.

Answer (score 5):

**Probably not really an answer**

... but it amuses me that it fits as much as it does. You are probably not

> the statesman and author BENJAMIN DISRAELI

even though

> the title ends with "dis Riley" which is not so far from "Disraeli"

and

> BENJAMIN is the name of the donkey in George Orwell's *Animal Farm* and hence a "big ol' ass".

Comment: Not the answer, but it definitely was amusing..

Comment: This is hilarious

Answer (score 2):

Things I've deciphered:

> Right acrostic is seven, there are 7 continents and 7 deadly sins, seven colours in the rainbow (which comes after rain, thanks to @gabbo1092), the only line to have 7 syllables is "My suffix straight up lies, bruv'" The acrostic of the 7th letter in each line (including spaces) is fift. Maybe means fifty or fifth. The fifth letter in the line with 7 syllables (including spaces) is U.

Which leads me to the conclusion that:

> The answer is YOU/ME. And I am feeling lucky.

Comment: To add to the sevens: (ROT13) Uvag gjb nsgre envasnyy ersreevat gb envaobj (juvpu vf frira yrggref) naq unf gur frira pbybhef EBLTOVI

Comment: Ohh great find @gabbo1092 :D

Comment: nice answer, the deciphered clues are correct up until the rainfall part, thanks to @gabbo1092 for that,  your final answer is wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

### **Partial Answer**

---

I believe the title is a reference to:

> Dirty Harry starring Clint Eastwood. In this film he says the [famous quote](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjpwdStscLdAhWJk1kKHUiFDXMQwqsBMAB6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D8Xjr2hnOHiM&usg=AOvVaw0c1yG7BmVrqBZwR_Da8sV6) "*You've got to ask yourself one question. Do I feel lucky? Well, do ya, punk?*"

Comment: although the movie reference has nothing to do with the intended answer but the quote was in fact taken from that dialogue..